# iOS - crash when click RUN in Xcode to physical iphone, works fine when clicking icon on phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

when I hit the run button in xcode, my app launches on my phone but crashes instantly (no error messages, no console log).

when I click my app icon on my phone, it launches and runs perfectly.

also, it never crashes at all when run in emulator.

this started happening after adding a collection view.

Comment: What iOS version is the iPhone running? You can check in Setting > General > About > Version

Comment: close xcode, reboot your device, sometimes the debugger can hang

Comment: problem has been ongoing for few days. Have tried close/restart many times.

Comment: CollectionViews are an iOS 6 SDK inclusion I think, so testing/running on your phone, which is running version 4 of iOS sounds like its the problem. If you update your iPhone software to iOS 6 it should work fine, failing that remove the collection view. Is my best guess. Not sure why it runs perfectly without xcode??

Comment: sorry Ric, thought you meant Xcode, which is running 4.6. The phone is running 6.1.2 on an iphone5.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` was added in iOS 6, and does not exist on older devices so the app crashes, however you can use something like [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) to support older devices.

Comment: crash is happening on an iphone 5 running 6.1.2

Comment: I'm not sure anymore sorry. I can only guess that there is some strange race condition in your code that causes it to crash when the debugger delays some part of it. Add some `NSLog`s to figure out where it could be. Start in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` like `NSLog(@"Launched");`

Comment: I ended up formatting/resetting my phone (for other reasons), and now it doesn't crash no more on running on the device.